# Restoring documents from being minimised

Tags: windows-7

When I have more than one Word or Excel doc minimised on my taskbar I cannot re-open them without right clicking and going to recently opened documents. This worked perfectly normally until a few days ago, when you would just need to left click on the Word symbol on the taskbar with the mouse and then choose the document you want to restore. Does anyone know a solution please? Many thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is one of those "when you see it, it makes sense" kind of bugs. Can you post a screenshot of what you see before and after? Feel free to use an empty document or two, or blur the content of the document itself. If you do not have enough reputation, feel free to use an image hosting service, and post links so others can attach it to your post for you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately a screenshot wouldn't be too helpful as the Word icon is on the task bar at the bottom of the screen and it doesn't do anything apart from 'jiggle' when clicked or hovered over...

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing a screenshot, so I can't be sure this is what happens, so this is my best shot given the little information you provided:

Rightclick your word icon, and choose un-pin from the menu.

Then through the start menu, launch word.

Now rightclick the word icon again, and choose pin to taskbar.

Somehow the link inside it doesn't work, but the files still open word okay. By doing the above, you'll fix the issue.